# debian stretch UUID package

Tags: debian, software-installation, uuid

I am running Debian 9.3 (Stretch). I am trying to install some tools from Vmware and it asks for a package  `UUID 0.03 or newer`. How can I upgrade UUID to newer version? It does not proceed any further due to this error.
Up to now I tried

```
apt-get install uuid-runtime
```

without any changes in the error. Any ideas on the name of the package and where to get it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [the `uuid` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/uuid):

```
sudo apt install uuid
```